# PHP error , PRIMARY key

Tags: php

i have a problem

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/u509660713/public_html/panel/inc/pages/adminpanel.p.php on line 66
```

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /home/u509660713/public_html/panel/inc/pages/adminpanel.p.php:68 Stack trace: #0 /home/u509660713/public_html/panel/inc/pages/adminpanel.p.php(68): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/u509660713/public_html/panel/inc/Config.class.php(267): include('/home/u50966071...') #2 /home/u509660713/public_html/panel/index.php(9): Config::getContent() #3 {main} thrown in /home/u509660713/public_html/panel/inc/pages/adminpanel.p.php on line 68

This is problem.

This is code:

```
        <?php 
if(isset($_POST['name23']) && isset($_POST['level23']) && isset($_POST['adminhelper']))
{
    if($_POST['adminhelper'] == "1") {
        $admin = 1;
    } else { 
        $admin = 2;
    }
    $helper = array(
        1 => "Admin",
        2 => "Helper"
        );
    if($_POST['level23'] >= 1) {
        if($_POST['adminhelper'] == "1") {
            $q = Config::$g_con->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET `Admin` = ? WHERE `name` = ?');
            $q->execute(array($_POST['level23'],$_POST['name23']));

        $texttt = "<b>AdmPanel:</b> Admin". Config::getData('users','name',$_SESSION['user']) ." <b>set</b> player ". Config::getID('users','name',$row->playername) .", admin: `enter code here`<b>".$_POST['level23']."</b>";
        $q = Config::$g_con->prepare('INSERT INTO `log_admin` (`iD`, `log`, `time`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
        $q->execute(array($texttt,Config::getData('users','name',$_SESSION['user']),Config::$_url[0]));


        } else { 
            $q = Config::$g_con->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET `Helper` = ? WHERE `name` = ?');
            $q->execute(array($_POST['level23'],$_POST['name23']));
        }
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Ai setat '. htmlspecialchars($helper[$_POST['adminhelper']]) .' <b>'. htmlspecialchars($_POST['level23']) .'</b> utilizatorului <b>'. htmlspecialchars($_POST['name23']) .'</b>!</div>';
    } else { 
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Nu poti seta nivelul 0 unui admin. Pentru asta poti folosi functia de remove de la sectiunea Staff</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

and this is data base

Please help me

Comment: It is very clear. if you look at the database, you will find 0 as one of the entries in the primary key position.

Comment: if iD is autoincrementd just leave it out of the insert, and mysql will take care of it

Comment: no redirect after an update allows a page refresh to double post

Comment: You are inseting a pieces of text holding some HTML as the `iD` If the `iD` is an integer that would explain it

Comment: And what is `Config::$_url[0]` that you are inserting into a column called `time`

Comment: @RiggsFolly "$_url "is "public static $_url = array();"

Comment: @developerwjk is not, when i want to change admin level another player show me this error.

Comment: Help me please.

Comment: mine was just a general comment; I figure the error is caused by what's mentioned in the first comment (or rather, second, i.e. auto_increment field, don't specify a value).

Comment: @developerwjk Oh, you saved me,thankss!